# unique values of an input relevant to the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form where a certain section has a table of inputs that are created for each row like below .

```html
<input type="text" class="input1" name="fname" />
<input type="text" class="input2" name="fname" />
<input type="text" class="input3" name="fname" />
<input type="text" class="input5" name="fname" />
```

These are created dynamically, the user controls how many rows, so there can be 5 or there can be 20.

I need to get the values of the inputs into an array, I am creating the array by looping through the `<tr>` that contains the inputs.

```
for (i = 0; i < $(".TRTR").length; i++) {
  // trying to capture the values here 
});
```

Then I am pushing it into an array.

```
arr.push(values)
```

As it stands I don't get the correct values. I want to get all values for each individual row, but I either get the first input values on every loop (by using the `.val()` method) or I get all values of every input within the whole table.

What I need to do, is have the input values of that row, then create a new object, and use the values of that row on that object as it continues to loop.

So if I had 4 rows, I would have 4 objects in the array each with the input values relevant to the row.

Example:

```txt
object 1 { value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4 }
object 2 { value 5, value 6, value 7, value 8 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us where the data of `values` currently comes from?

Comment: its captured with a click event, the value is whatever value is entered in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` to build a 2d array of the input values within each table row. Try this:

```js
let values = $('tr').map((_, tr) => [$(tr).find(':input').map((_, input) => input.value).get()]).get();
console.log(values);

/* longer version of the above, although more readable:
let values = $('tr').map((_, tr) => {
  return [$(tr).find(':input').map((_, input) => input.value).get()
]).get();
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input1" name="fname" value="1_1">
      <input type="text" class="input2" name="fname" value="1_2">
      <input type="text" class="input3" name="fname" value="1_3">
      <input type="text" class="input5" name="fname" value="1_4">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="input1" name="fname" value="2_1">
      <input type="text" class="input2" name="fname" value="2_2">
      <input type="text" class="input3" name="fname" value="2_3">
      <input type="text" class="input5" name="fname" value="2_4">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: one thing rory, This array, it is being pushed into the backend where i am then deserializing it, any idea on how i would give the items titles etc so i can reference them once desialized

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) As it's an array of items you can reference them by index. For example the first item (`1_1`) would be `data[0][0]` in the server side, where `data` is the array reference

Comment: apparently, someone decided to come along and delete my compliments ...